# "Ran into a RPAREN where it wasn't expected" when using "->>"

Tags: hy

I have the following code:

```
(require [hyrule [-> ->>]])

(defn static/freezer [value freezer]
                      (cond [(not value) (setv freezer [])]
                            [(isinstance value list)
                             (do (if (not (isinstance freezer list)) (setv freezer []))
                                 (.extend freezer value)
                                 (setv freezer (->> (lfor i
                                                          (lfor j freezer :if j j)
                                                          (if (isinstance i list) i [i]))
                                                    (list)
                                                    (chain #*))))]
                            [True (raise (TypeError f"Sorry! The 'm/freezer' can only accept lists or non-truthy values!"))])
  (return freezer))

(print (static/freezer [[1 2] [3 4] 5))
```

... but am getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/runpy.py", line 267, in run_path
    code, fname = _get_code_from_file(run_name, path_name)
  File "/home/shadowrylander/bakery/test.hy", line 12
    (chain #*))))]
             ^
hy.lex.exceptions.LexException: Ran into a RPAREN where it wasn't expected.
```

I am assuming the `->>` macro isn't taking effect, as every bracket checks out, but neither `eval-when-compile` nor `eval-after-compile` helps.

Comment: Apparently, as mentioned by @Kodiologist in their answer below, it would be the incomplete `chain #*` in the `->>` macro.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested by the error message, `(chain #*)` is not lexically legal. `#*`, as well as `#**`, must be followed by a form. The underlying idea is that `#*` and `#**`, like `(` and `"`, are not forms themselves, but characters that can be used along with some other characters to construct forms, namely `(unpack-iterable …)` and `(unpack-mapping …)`. [#1730](https://github.com/hylang/hy/issues/1730) discusses some related issues. At any rate, lexing happens before any macros are expanded, so `->>` can't get around this.

Comment: So should I simply use `(chain (unpack-iterable ... ))` in the `->>` macro instead?

Comment: @ShadowRylander That's not how `->>` works, unless I'm missing something. The easiest thing to do here is just use ordinary, prefix calls in place of `->>`.

Comment: Sorry; I meant something like this: `(-> (lfor i (lfor j freezer :if j j) (if (isinstance i list) i [i])) (list) (unpack-iterable) (chain))`, which would create the list, ... make it a list? I have no idea why that is there... , then unpack the list and chain all the elements.